# Hi! Could you tell me if I should run usual OLS regression or panel regression?

Tags: panel-data, dataset, stata

The assignment is following:
The dataset contains information on the compensation of CEOs in 170 US firms over the 2005-2006 period. It contains detailed information on compensation and also information on the size, profits and market values of the firms. Firms (and their CEOs) are observed twice: in 2005 and 2006, allowing you to analyze intertemporal relationships.
The exercise is intended to analyze the link between firm size, firm profitability, and CEO compensation.
Estimate the following equation:
Log_compensationit = α + β Profitabilityit + γ Sizeit + μit
i: index for firms
t: index for time

I ran random effects  regressions in Stata (Hausman test showed it is RE).
But there are only 2 years, so is it panel data? Or we should do usual OLS model?
Also in the equation we should estimate there is no variable for individual effects.

Comment: Why not estimate all three models, pool OLS, fixed effects, and random effects. Check if there are any differences in the estimates, and explain why... You observe the same units over time, so sure, its a panal - so can, and should control for fixed effects